# Dell studio laptop shows white screen only

Tags: laptop, laptop-display, dell-studio

I have a dell studio laptop. My screen shows white screen and on pressing with fingers on some parts of the screen, the display comes back but has some lining. Do I need to replace the screen totally or replacing the lcd video cables will fix this ?

[image]

[image: after pressing on screen]

Answer (score 0):

Typically the video cable never goes bad, the lcd has a converter for the fluorescent backlight that will go bad sometimes. If your screen is led backlit, that will not have a converter and is much more reliable. You can count on it being the LCD screen itself. You can confirm by plugging in an desktop monitor. LCD screens can be easy to replace most of the time.